# Import-CSV list below each other

Tags: powershell

I use this to get a list of Account Numbers in a file:

```
$List = Import-Csv $dest\$FPP.txt -Delimiter '~' | Foreach-Object {$_.'Account No'}
```

Then I send the list via email by using the $List variable.

But the list of accounts is then displayed next to each other - how can I display the below one another like they do when running in the ISE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the result to the `Out-String` cmdlet. This will turn the collection of strings to a single string

```
$List = Import-Csv ...| Foreach ... | Out-String
```